# How to implement Symbol.iterator?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to create a subclass of Set, and since I cannot just simply extend from it, I'm wrapping its functionality.

I'm trying to implement the Symbol.iterator method, but Flow is having none of it.

This is the code that I have:

```
/* @flow */
class CSet<T> {
    _set: Set<T>;
    [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T> {
        return this._set[Symbol.iterator];
    }
}

var a: CSet = new CSet();
for(var b of a){

}

core.js:309:5,29: property @@iterator
Property not found in
test.js:2:7,10: CSet

test.js:4:2,6:2: 
computed property keys not supported
```

The second error isn't as huge of a deal since I can easily suppress it. I'm wondering if I'm just doing something wrong all-together though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Flow doesn't currently have general support for symbols, the way it represents `Symbol.iterator` is hacky and basically prevents the ability to define iterators in userspace for now (its support only works in library definitions) :(

Specifically Flow expects that an iterable has a `@@iterator` property on them (which is certainly not a valid property name -- but this was a temporary hack to get support in library definitions).

So until proper symbol support lands, your best bet for a workaround here would be to create a library definition for this module that uses this `@@iterator` property for Flow's understanding:

```
// RealModule.js
export class CSet {
    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return this._set[Symbol.iterator];
    }
}
```

.

```
// RealModule.FlowLibDef.js
declare module RealModule {
    declare class CSet<T> {
        _set: Set<T>;
        @@iterator(): Iterator<T>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
// @flow
class MyCollection<T> {
    /*:: @@iterator(): Iterator<T> { return ({}: any); } */

    // $FlowFixMe: computed property
    [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T> {
        // NOTE: this could just as easily return a different implementation
        return new MyIterator(this);
    }
}

class MyIterator<+T> {
    /*:: @@iterator(): Iterator<T> { return (this: any); } */

    // $FlowFixMe: computed property
    [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T> {
        return this;
    }

    next(): IteratorResult<T, void> {
        return { done: false, value: someT };
        // or return { done: true, value: undefined };
    }
}

for (const value of new MyCollection()) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

The reason this works is that flow interprets `/*:: code */` as though it were flow code in the source, except that it is commented out at runtime therefore does not actually affect the code.

Flow intrinsically knows about the `@@iterator` method, despite it not being valid JavaScript, thus we define it as existing, returning an `Iterator<T>`, and returning a value that works for it (i.e. an empty object cast as `any`).

The computed property method is then ignored completely by flow, as if it were not defined at all. It is crucial that you actually return a valid `Iterator<T>` from the method, otherwise things will break at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a trick that lets you mark a user-defined class as iterable, without needing to write and maintain a parallel libdef for your entire class.

The key is to write a dedicated superclass that implements `[Symbol.iterator]()`, and provide a libdef just for that superclass:

```
// IterableBase.js
export default class IterableBase {
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this._Symbol_iterator();
  }
}
```

```
// IterableBase.js.flow
// @flow
declare class IterableBase<T> {
  @@iterator(): Iterator<T>;
}
export default IterableBase;
```

Now you can have your custom class extend `IterableBase` and implement the substitute method name:

```
// RealModule.js
// @flow
import IterableBase from './IterableBase';

class CSet<T> extends IterableBase<T> {
  _Symbol_iterator(): Iterator<T> {
    ...
  }
}
```

This is obviously still a hack, but it should be easier and safer than the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

try this javascript code

```
// module -- start

let map = new WeakMap();

class Foo {
  constructor(any) {
    map.set(this, new Set(any));
  }
  values() {
    return map.get(this).values();
  }
  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this.values();
  }
}

// module -- end


for(let item of new Foo([1,2,3])) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

see

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set
2. [sandbox](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?code=%0A%2F%2F%20module%20--%20start%0A%0Alet%20map%20%3D%20new%20WeakMap()%3B%0A%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(any)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20map.set(this%2C%20new%20Set(any))%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20values()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20map.get(this).values()%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%5BSymbol.iterator%5D()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20this.values()%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20module%20--%20end%0A%0A%0Afor(let%20item%20of%20new%20Foo(%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D))%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log(item)%3B%0A%7D)

Comment: My bad, I should of been more specific. This is in regards to Flow not type checking properly. Flow doesn't consider Set to have a values() function.